# Svelte Kit Endpoint gives me 404

Tags: api, svelte, endpoint, sveltekit

I made an Svelte Kit its working in my local with no problem but when i build it like this:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';

export default {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            fallback: 'index.html',
        })
    }
};
```

And gives me 3 folders and they are: client, prerendered, server.

I'm uploading this 3 folders in my hosting and move the folder files into root folder. Everythings works with no problem BUT i have an api that sends mail. It's gives me 404? Send mail is working in localhost but not working in hosting. I can't fixed it. In manifest.json:

```
{
    type: 'endpoint',
    id: "api/sendMail",
    pattern: /^\/api\/sendMail\/?$/,
    names: [],
    types: [],
    load: () => import('./entries/endpoints/api/sendMail/_server.js')
},
```

The path is correct by the way.

The folders in hosting:
[Photo](https://i.hizliresim.com/e76klbp.jpg)

What can i do?

Answer (score 1):

By specifying a fallback page, this means you're turning SPA mode on, so you can't use server endpoints.

From the adapter-static [readme](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/adapter-static#spa-mode):

> You can use adapter-static to create a single-page app or SPA by
> specifying a fallback page.

The reason this is working local in `dev`:

> During development, SvelteKit will still attempt to server-side render
> your routes. This means accessing things that are only available in
> the browser (such as the window object) will result in errors, even
> though this would be valid in the output app. To align the behavior of
> SvelteKit's dev mode with your SPA, you can add export const ssr =
> false to your root +layout.

Comment: Okay thank for comment. What can i do for work?